# Why on compile MVC starts on the wrong controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have a Controller named HomeController, a folder named Home, and a View called Index. I also have another Controller named TestEditController, a folder named TestEdit, and a View called Index. For some reason, when I compile it the URL: `http://localhost:4097/` doesn't point to Home/Index but to TestEdit/Index. I went to the Properties > Start Action > Specific Page ... and left the textbox blank. Note: putting a `/` doesn't work. I've cleaned, build, rebuild the project/solution. But still getting the same issue. Here's my Global.asax files:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "SectionsData", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{prodno}/{instid}/{section}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Sections", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Sections", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{prodno}/{instid}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MainProducts", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{prodno}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional  } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Catalogs", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: The routes will take the first match.  Since the TestEdit route has all its URL parameters optional, it matches on that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matching is too generic.  try this instead:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionsData", // Route name
        "TestEdit/Sections/{id}/{prodno}/{instid}/{section}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Sections", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Sections", // Route name
        "TestEdit/Index/{id}/{prodno}/{instid}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "MainProducts", // Route name
        "Home/Main/{id}/{prodno}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional, prodno = UrlParameter.Optional  } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Catalogs", // Route name
        "Home/Products/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

...but really, you don't need a lot of these routes.

Comment: Oh. Really? How many do you think I should have or really need?

Comment: Well, Catalogs and MainProducts will be handled properly with the default route, and Sections and SectionsData can be merged into one route.

Comment: But wouldn't the prodno end up as a querystring if I let the default route (as is) handle it?

Comment: Whups! yeah I missed that.  But you can fix that by referencing it in your default route.

Answer (score 1):

Because both SectionsData and Sections Route has all other parameters optional, they will match before the default route.